# Reuse piece of code in C

Tags: c

Consider :

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define BULK_UPDATER while(1){   \
                       x=y=++z;  \
                       break;    \
                     }

int main(void)
{
  int x,y,z; //defined
  x=y=z=100;
  BULK_UPDATER;
  printf("x : %d y : %d z : %d\n",x,y,z);
return 0;
}
```

The `while(1)` loop makes a full statement and so it is allowed with `#define` here. The idea is to reuse a piece of code that appears frequently.
This test case  doesn't make any sense at all but I hope my intention is clear.

Is there an alternative/better way of doing it?

Comment: why hide logic like that?  create a method/function instead?

Comment: Creating a method is a recommended alternate way.

Comment: If you must use this macro (a dubious proposition), then use `#define bulk_updater do { x = y = ++z; } while (0)` so that you can use `if (something == otherthing) bulk_updater; else …`.  If you use `while`, you'll create a syntax error.

Comment: @MitchWheat : For simple programs, i may not use a function which makes me deal with variable scope among other things.. Also for more complex programs i don't use this at all for the same reason you mentioned.

Comment: Why would you want to put an unconditional break in an infinite loop ? Just don't put a loop at all it will have the same effect. And put this in a function. And please name your macros with capital letters.

Comment: IF you don't want to use a function then a macro is indeed the best way to go. Note that a macro can take parameters.

Comment: If you insist on this, I recommend you surround everything with bracers { } for scope issue, so you don't end up with multiple declaration.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thanks for the suggestion on exit control `do-while` loop. It eliminates the need for `break` as well.

Comment: @TimF : \@JonathanLeffler has already suggested an alternative that eliminates the need for an infinite while loop here. And thanks for that suggestion on uppercase macro names. I usually follow that :D

Comment: My question was not only about the while loop. Why do you need a loop for a piece of code that has to be executed only once, no more no less ?

Comment: If you are not planning on a *multi-line* macro, then there is nothing wrong with `#define bulk_updater { x = y = ++z; }` other than the obvious limitations of requiring `x, y, z` and only `x, y, z` to be declared and within scope visibility. Perhaps `bulk_updater(a, b, c) do { (a) = (b) = ++(c) } while (0)`? You could at least chose those value you wished to bulk update and add `typefo` operator for some validation of values ([**5.6 Referring to a Type with typeof**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Typeof.html)

Comment: Basic common sense says [macros are evil](https://www.google.com/search?q="macros+are+evil"). Don't use one where a function can do.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are alternatives. First of all the body of the macro is not that huge. Compare:

```
x=y=++z;
```

with

```
bulk_updater;
```

The macro doesn't even save your precious fingers or disk space. Whether the former or latter is more readable is up to you (personally I prefer the former as it's clear what the statement does and it is more compact).

You could also create a function that does what you want, but then you would have to send parameters to do it:

```
void bulk_updater(int* x, int* y, int *z) {
    *x = *y = ++*z;
}

...

bulk_updater(&x, &y, &z);
```

This even more doesn't save your fingers or disk space. As always, which is better is a matter of opinion.

A more compact version of the function can be achieved by putting `x`, `y` and `z` in a struct:

```
struct xyz {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

void bulk_update(struct xyz* p)
{
    p->x = p->y = ++p->z;
}

...

struct xyz xyz;

bulk_update(&xyz);
```

Even though it may seem clumsy, it may be justifiable if you have more meaningful operations on the `xyz` triple.

By the way it's normally recommended that you use upper case for macro names (so that one knows it's a macro). And if you want it to work as a statement you should use `do { ... } while(0)` instead, that way it will only be valid with a semi-colon after and a semi-colon after will not make it two statements (as your solution does):

```
#define BULK_UPDATER do { x=y=++z; } while(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say you want to use a function to do the update, but you do not want the runtime overhead that a function introduces(since you are doing a small operation inside the function)

So use [macro functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215171/function-like-macro-definition-in-c). For this case,

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define BULK_UPDATER(a,b,c) a = b = ++c
int main(void)
{
  int x,y,z; //defined
  x=y=z=100;
  BULK_UPDATER(x,y,z);
  printf("x : %d y : %d z : %d\n",x,y,z);

  BULK_UPDATER(x,y,z);
  printf("x : %d y : %d z : %d\n",x,y,z);

  int x1,y1,z1 = 45;
  BULK_UPDATER(x1,y1,z1);
  printf("x1 : %d y1 : %d z1 : %d\n",x1,y1,z1);
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x : 101 y : 101 z : 101
x : 102 y : 102 z : 102
x : 46 y : 46 z : 46
```